"NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl" promise always resolve to 'javascript:void(0)' when calling it inside a Flow called by a list view button
As the title says, I'm finding it impossible from a screen in a 'Screen flow' that contains an LWC that tries to use NavigationMixIn to either generate the URL or to use the "Navigate" when called from A LIST VIEW BUTTON. The GenerateUrl promise will solve to 'javascript:void(0);' and the Navigate will fail silently.
Here is the js code:
import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";
export default class TestCmp extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    async connectedCallback() {
        this.url = await this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
            type: "standard__objectPage",
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: "Account",
                actionName: "home"
            }
        });
    }
}

Checking the DOM, I notice that the flow is "called" within an iframe, which is displayed to us. So if you try to use either window.location.reload() or window.location.href = 'some url', that won't work at all to navigate away.
I hope this makes sense, but I'm happy to discuss further!

The issue may be due to the fact that when you trigger a flow via a List View Button, the flow is rendered inside an iframe. Navigation commands like window.location.reload() or window.location.href might not behave as expected when used inside an iframe due to security restrictions in browsers or how Salesforce handles iframe navigation.
Potential Solutions:
Use Navigation Outside the Flow Context: Since your flow is being displayed inside an iframe, you might want to perform the navigation outside the iframe itself. Consider triggering a Lightning Page or Flow through a different mechanism (like a Quick Action or a direct button click) instead of using it from a List View Button.
Check Flow and LWC Scope: If this navigation behavior is essential within the iframe, you may need to rethink how the LWC interacts with the flow. One approach could be to use event-based communication between the iframe and the parent page to trigger the navigation.
Test Navigation from Outside the Flow: As a test, remove the flow context entirely and check if the NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl works correctly from a standalone component outside a flow. This will help confirm whether the iframe is the root cause of the issue.
Alternative to NavigationMixin: You can also try using custom events or Salesforce’s force:navigateToSObject or lightning:navigateToRelatedList in your flow, which may behave better inside an iframe.
You can also check for any new limitations Salesforce might have placed on navigations happening inside flows launched from list view buttons in recent releases.
